# ksh: How to get all "log" directories ordered by most recent activity?

Tags: find, ksh, ls

I would like to order a set of 50 directories based on most its recently written file in its respective `log` subdir. So, each directory has scripts and a log subdir. The idea is, to find out which code is most active so we migrate that first.

I started by something like 
`for dir in $(find . -name log -type d); do printf $dir; ls -lcrt $dir | tail -n 1; done`

but this gives a messy result, that needs further parsing in order to sort on date. Maybe there is a simpler way?

thank you

- update: since there are many files per directory, the first step would be to get the newest per directory, and iterate over that.
  So I built a double for loop, that did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: since there are many files per directory, the first step would be to only get the newest one per directory (ls -lh |tail -1; something like that), and iterate over that. So I built a double for loop, which won't win any beauty contest, but got me the results.

Answer (score 0):

This method may not be able to 100% solve your problem, but it is easy to use.

Assuming that there are at most 99 file in past 2 days, then

```
find . -type f -mtime -2 | xargs -n 99 ls -ltr | grep '/log/'
```

This command will find all files with modification time in past 2 days and then do a ls -ltr sorting and then filter the /log/ directory

Hope this can help a little.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply - the idea is to get each newest file per directory, and compare these.